# Ida Disassembly Name Mangling

Tags: windows, assembly, disassembly, ida, name-mangling

When using IDA Pro I sometimes get names like `??0CSGString@@QAE@ABV0@@Z` in the idata segment. They look weird but that's because of name mangling. But sometimes I get names like `__imp__DoPopup@4` which does not seem to be this way because of name mangling. In addition to that I also got the same function in the idata segment of another disassembly but with the name `DoPopup`. So my question: Is the second one a valid function name? Or is it just a name IDA made up for it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `@4` isn't C++ name mangling; it's a convention for stdcall functions to be decorated with the number of bytes of stack args they pop with `ret 4` for example instead of a plain `ret`.  This produces linker errors instead of hard-to-debug runtime weirdness in case of a mismatch.

In C++, the function is `extern "C" DoPopup(some_4byte_type)`.
We can't infer the return type.

`__imp__foo` is the DLL import thunk for asm symbol `_foo` in the DLL, so this isn't actually C++ `_imp__DoPopup`.  This is in addition to C++ name mangling, I assume, so if it hadn't been `extern "C"` then you could maybe have had `__imp__??0CSGString@@QAE@ABV0@@Z` for am import of that function.

Decorating symbols with a leading underscore is a thing for 32-bit Windows, although it doesn't apply here because `__imp__` is its own form of decoration that replaces it.

---

32-bit fastcall also uses callee-pops with the same name mangling, but the first 2 args are passed in registers.  (I forget whether the @n includes the space the register args would have used or not.)

---

Note that Windows x64 doesn't add a leading underscore to asm symbol names vs. their C name, and uses a different calling convention which is not callee-pops, so no @number decorations would be used there either.

Comment: Does the `__imp_` prefix has anything to do with this convention or is that something that IDA made up?

Comment: @abcdefghi019283: I'd assume it's part of the actual C++ program, like an internal helper.  I don't use Windows or develop for it, and don't use IDA, so it's not something I've actually come across.  I just know how Windows asm calling conventions work, but not really more complex stuff like DLL imports or whatever.  Maybe "imp" stands for import and this is related to a DLL function?  Single-stepping through it might be helpful to figure out what it's doing.

Comment: @PeterCordes Yes, `imp` is the thunk function corresponding to an import (from a DLL).